# trying to do registration to display in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, registration

Hi im a really noob at this, im doing a very simple project, DOES'NT need to be secure or anything

Im trying to do a registration page and display the information to to my php page i looked at many guides and still find it very confusing

These are my codes

This is my displaying table in my php, working

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

mysql_select_db('login');

$sql="SELECT * FROM registranttb";

$records=mysql_query($sql);

?>
 <table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
     <tr>


 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Course Applied for</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Contact Number</th>
 <th>Registration Date</th>
 <tr>
 <h1>Course</h1>

     <?php 

    while($registranttb=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {

echo "<tr>";


echo "<td>".$registranttb['Name']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$registranttb['Course']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$registranttb['Email']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$registranttb['Contact']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$registranttb['Date']."</td>";

   }
   ?>
```

i have no clue what to do from here on out....Btw when i edit the files in mysql it can display the information of that

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML in not correct.  You cannot output a `<h1>` between `<tr>` tags, and you are not closing your `<tr>` tags or your `<table>` tag.

```
<h1>Course</h1>

<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Course Applied for</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Contact Number</th>
    <th>Registration Date</th>
  <tr>

<?php while($registranttb=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) { ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $registranttb['Name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registranttb['Course'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registranttb['Email'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registranttb['Contact'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registranttb['Date'] ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```